# how to use the age() function in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a column in the students table called birthdate. i need to find students over the age of 12.

```
select ......, age(timestamp 'birthdate') as StudentAge
from students
.....
where StudentAge > 11
```

I dont know if thats the proper syntax or if im using the correct function for the situation

Comment: `age(birthdate) `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think most of your confusion comes from unfamiliarity with Postgres's rich type system, and the syntax it uses.

In [the page on date/time functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html), the `age` function is listed with two forms. Assuming you want to compare to "today", you want the form with a single argument:

> Function: age(timestamp)
>   Return type: interval
>   Description: Subtract from current_date (at midnight)
>   Example: age(timestamp '1957-06-13')
>   Result: 43 years 8 mons 3 days

So, you have a function which takes a value of type `timestamp`, and returns a value of type `interval`.

The example shows the input being specified as `timestamp '1957-06-13'`; this is just a way of creating a value of type `timestamp` from a hard-coded value - like creating an object in an object-oriented language. In your query, `birthdate` is not a hard-coded value, it's the name of a column, so this is not the syntax you want. If the column is of type `timestamp`, you can just use `age(birthdate)` directly; if not, you might need to convert it, e.g. `age(CAST(birthdate AS timestamp))`.

The output is of type `interval`, not a number of years, so comparing it against `12` is unlikely to do what you want. Instead, you should compare it against another `interval` value. Similar to the `timestamp '1957-06-13'` example, you can write `interval '12 years'` to directly create an `interval` value representing 12 years.

So your comparison would look like `age(birthdate) >= interval '12 years'`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that tutorial you are talking about, but [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-select-lists.html#QUERIES-COLUMN-LABELS) has the following to say about column labels:

> The entries in the select list can be assigned names for subsequent processing, such as for use in an `ORDER BY` clause or for display by the client application.

Observe the *subsequent* here: The `SELECT` list is (logically) processed *after* the `WHERE` clause, so you cannot use column labels there.

You'll have to repeat the expression. This is in accordance with the SQL standard.

Moreover, `birthdate` is not a string literal, so don't quote it. And remove the `timestamp`.